# Can I transform variables to comply with conditions on order of integration in an ARDL model?

Tags: time-series, logarithm, differencing, ardl

If log variable have a unit root, can you then difference it?

For ARDL model variables should not be I(2) or more. Variables of log form are I(2). Would it be a problem to difference it.

What I am asking is:
is it the varibales included in the actual model that need to be I(0) or I(1). so that it does not matter if the raw data were I(2) as long as you use the first difference of this which is I(1) (or I(0)) in model/analysis.

or stated differently:
If log X is I(2) it is not appropriate to include
but you can include
the differenced log X if it is I(1) or I(0)

Comment: yes helpful and clear, I'm sorry. I don't have enough "reputation" to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it right. The variables that appear in the model must be well behaved (there are some conditions they must satisfy) so that the model and especially the estimator(s) would work as expected. The transformations that you apply outside of the model to make the variables well behaved are beyond the scope of the conditions.